# Instagram API hash to return all follows no longer works

Tags: ios, api, instagram

For months, I have used the following hash to get all follows of a given logged in users back from the Instagram API:

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/follows?count=-1&access_token=%@

The count=-1 being the key parameter to achieve that.

My app started to return empty dictionaries back from the Instagram API from one day to the next.

I found out that this was linked to the count=-1 no longer working on the Instagram API.

Would anyone know what the new syntax might be now?

I couldn't find anything on other web sources.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Just update the url to

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/USERID/follows?access_token=TOKEN&count=COUNT
```

Where:

- USERID - your user id
- TOKEN - the access token
- COUNT - how many users you want get

Comment: Hi Tiago: so users/USERID instead of users/self changes everything?  How do I extract the USERID from the accessToken string?

Comment: @ArseneLavaux, the users/self/follows are not on the API docs... I don't know if it was removed or if never exists. Take a look: http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/relationships/. In the accessToken, the digits before the . (point) are the user id.